# Add to favorites ( multiple model )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a new to rails but I have a big problem with my app.

**Business Logic**
  - User can **favorite** restaurants, menus, items.
We have :

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :items, :dependent=>:destroy
     has_many :menus, :dependent=> :destroy
     belongs_to :owner, :class_name => 'User'
end
class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :restaurant
     has_many :items,:dependent=>:destroy
end
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :restaurant
     belongs_to :menu
end
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :restaurants
end
```

Could someone help me resolve my problem ?

Thanks for your support

**p/s**: Sorry for my english, i'm vietnamese.

Comment: And what exactly is your problem?

Comment: I need help to build a modeling favorite from User to many model (Restaurant, Item, Menu). Thanks you !

Answer (score 3):

You need to build a polymorphic association between a `User` and a `Favoritable` item. This is done using `polymorphic` association bellow:

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :favoritable, polymorphic: true
end

class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :favoritable, polymorphic: true
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :favoritable, polymorphic: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favorites, as: :favoritable
end
```

Then you can retrieve user's favorites with the following:

```
user = User.first
user.favorites
# => [...]
```

You can build a new favorite using:

```
user.favorites.build(favorite_params)
```

Or you can assign a favoritable object directly using:

```
user.favorites << Restaurant.find(1)
user.favorites << Menu.find(1)
user.favorites << Item.find(1)
```

More information about [polymorphic associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

Comment: Users click into restaurant, restaurant have many menus, click into menu , menu have many items.
I user can favorite items or menus or restaurants.
Please help syntax to do this ? (retrieve or save favorite)

Comment: This is part of another question. Beside, we are not going to make your application ourself, please show your attempts to solve your issues.

Comment: @QuốcNT you should ask for a coke too

Comment: @Pierre: I don't think it's another question. Following your association above. I don't know how to do it ? Please describe more details your solution. Thanks you.

Comment: You'll find more details about your questions. The association are classic rails association and you could find more details within the link I provided ;)